# The best incremental hash function for hash table

Tags: hash

Which *incremental* hash function is the best for a generic hash table implementation ?

I need to search a message, for example "ABC", in the hash table. If the message is in the hash table, then append short piece of information, for example "D", to the message, then search message "ABCD" in the hash table. Repeatedly append more information until the whole information doesn't exist in the hash table.

I need to do a lot this kind of search, so an efficient (fast to calculate and low collision rate) incremental hash function is very important to my algorithm.

Comment: It depends what your target data is.  Have you tried creating a representative sample data set and testing different algorithms?

Comment: You might want to mention what programming language you're using, in case someone can point you at a pre-existing library that does what you describe.

Comment: I'm using C++, the messages are just snippets of natural language.